# Setting a Variable = to a string in a text file

Tags: string, bash, substitution, cat

I am trying to place a line of a text file, directly in a mail function.  The string has the ' ' around it in the text file.

```
mailx -s "New Member" "cat ../address"
```

A line in `../address` is  `'my-email@gmail.com'`   including the `'   '` quotes.

The `cat ../address` is not the best way of doing it but I do not know any other way to try.

Required result should be:

```
mailx -s "New Member" 'my-email@gmail.com'
```

Comment: You can do: `mailx -s "New Member" $(</path/to/address)`

Comment: Note that the file *includes* the single quotes, which need to be stripped before it can be used as a valid address by `mailx`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I am trying it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the literal `'` chars. from the line in order for the address to be passed correctly to `mailx`:

There's more than one way to do it:

```
mailx -s "New Member" "$(tr -d "'" < ../address)"

mailx -s "New Member" "$(xargs < ../address)"
```

Note: The above assumes that `../address` contains only 1 line.

@chepner makes an important point:

> storing the quotes in the file and then reading them in [and using the result unquoted] is *not* the same as quoting the command substitution.

To elaborate on this further:

- The OP shows `'my-email@gmail.com'` as the desired argument to pass to `mailx`. In this *direct* form of single-quoting, *bash will remove the quotes* (see `Quote Removal` section in `man bash`) before handing the - unexpanded - string *contents, without the quotes,* to `mailx`.
- ***Indirect** quoting does NOT work*: Reading in a string that happens to contain literal quote characters around it is NOT subject to quote removal by bash, so the *enclosing quotes are passed through as part of the string* - `mailx` would see an *invalid* email address that starts (and ends) with a `'`.
- Therefore, the solution is:

  - remove the quotes from the input string first
  - then use *direct* quoting to *protect the result* from (further) shell expansion; note that *double*-quoting is needed so as to make sure the command substitution (`($...)`) is evaluated.

Comment: Deleting my answer as redundant, but want to emphasize for the OP that storing the quotes in the file and then reading them in is not the same as quoting the command substitution.

Comment: @chepner: I was about to up-vote yours for making that very point :) I'll incorporate it into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use backticks for command substitution. I assume there is only one line in the file.

```
mailx -s "New Member" `cat ../address`
```

An alternative/better form for backticks is `$()`

```
mailx -s "New Member" $(cat ../address)
```

Comment: Don't use backticks: use `$(...)`, which is both more readable and nestable.

Comment: @chepner, is `$()` compatible with the Bourne shell, or is it a bashism?

Comment: @SzG: It's part of the POSIX standard - see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03

Comment: Also, note that POSIX != Bourne shell. The actual Bourne shell is relatively limited compared to the standard, but the two are often confused because the standard specifies the shell be available as `/bin/sh`, which was the traditional name of the Bourne shell.

Comment: @chepner: Excellent point, thanks for making that clear. @SzG: Note that the input file contains literal `'` chars, which must be stripped first - see @chepner's comments.

Comment: The OP stated he wants the quotes.

Comment: @chepner: Which one is most portable, the backticks, or `$()`?

Comment: Thank you for answering the question.  Also the additional comments of others.

Comment: Both are equally portable.

Comment: @SzG: Re quoting: please see the explanation I added to my answer.